# Are there "measurable" properties?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Consider two measurable spaces $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B})$, consisting of sets $X$ and $Y$ and some $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ defined on each of them respectively.

Suppose we defined that $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ were "measurably homeomorphic" if and only if there existed a bijection $h: X \to Y$ that also implictly defined a bijection between $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, akin to how a homeomorphism between topological spaces also defines a bijection between topologies.

**What are some good references to learn and study what properties of $\sigma$-algebras are conserved under "measurable homeomorphism"?** Is the study of such "measurable properties", akin to the study of topological properties as things conserved under homeomorphism, trivial or not? (Trivial here meaning, for example, that nearly all measurable spaces are measurably homeomorphic or something like that.)

Comment: Have you looked at even the simplest examples? Are $X=\{0,1\}=Y$ with ${\cal A}=\{\emptyset,X\}$ and $B=\{\emptyset,\{0\},\{1\},Y\}$ measurably homeomorphic? Perhaps they are "something like that". I don't know.

Comment: The example is not meant to be a serious supposition---as you can see, it can be trivially disproved---but it is a quick way to communicate what I believe may be a reason such properties are not studied, namely that there may be a much "smaller" variety of distinct $\sigma$-algebras up to "measurable homeomorphism" vs. topology. Consider that, in the study of measure (not measurable) spaces, there is only one standard Borel space of a non-discrete Polish space up to direct isomorphism, rendering the study of their properties trivial. Nevertheless, I'll change that line to avoid confusion.

Comment: Nearly all does not sound much better than perhaps all. Intuitively I think the following. In a topology ${\cal T}$ the complement of an open set is closed, unlike in a $\sigma$-algebra where the complement of a measurable set is measurable. This leads to the situation that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is a much larger collection of sets than the natural topology (induced by the Euclidean metric). Therefore, there are a lot more measurable mappings than continuous ones. This destroys properties that are [preserved under homeomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism#Properties).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the concept you're looking for is *Borel isomorphism*, as defined in definition $1.2.4$ on p.$3$ of
[these notes](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/c/02/02-156.pdf#3).  Those notes would appear to be a good starting point for learning more about the concept. You need to be aware, however, that the term "Borel isomorphism" also appears to be used to refer to a related, but less general, concept.